# How do I write in log file from start instead append it to end of file

Tags: asp.net, exception, logging, io, stream

I have following code  for log file 
which will create a log file and write log into that file.

But I want to write that log into file in DESC order
so that recent log text will come first.

```
 string FilePath = Path(MYLOG.txt");

                if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = null;
                    fileBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("My Log -\n");
                    using (Stream streamToWrite = File.Create(FilePath))
                    {
                        streamToWrite.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                        streamToWrite.Flush();
                    }
```

> I mean want to write new content from start not to end of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do

```
string currentContent = String.Empty;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                currentContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            }
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, newContent + currentContent );
```

Comment: why to do this ? can not I directly make it in DESC order?

Comment: I mean want to write new content from start not to end of the file

Comment: well as per my knowledge only you can do is append text in log files which will add text at the end and to write it in start you have to  do this code please mark answer if it helped you thanks...

Comment: newContent  ? from where ? and code unable to make Log file content in reverse order